How can I embed a react app and assicoated css file in a Power Apps Canvas App?
I can't find a solution for this, but I have a ReactJS app which consists of a simple index.html, app.js and app.css.
I want to embed this app inside a page in my Power Apps Canvas App. Is this possible? And where could I host the HTML, JS and CSS files if they need to be stored outside the app?
Thanks.

Anyone know the answer?
